# Not getting data using JSON from openweather.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get weather information from openweather.com api with the help of geo-location (lattitude and longitude). I can not get it why it is not getting data. Here is my code:

```
function getWeather(lat, long){
  console.log(lat +" "+ long); //23.8008983 90.3541741
  $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lon="+long+"&units=imperial&APPID=7a26948f2294e4d5754c951a6aaf7cf8", function(json) {  
    console.log("Successfully data recieved");
    var temp = Math.round(json.main.temp);
    console.log(temp);
    $("#weather").value(temp);
  });
```

I try to print "Successfully data recieved" in console but it does not print. I assume the callback is not happening. it is confirmed that function calling (getWeather()) is okay as I am getting values of latitude and longitude (I kept those values in comment). I badly need your help. I manually typed the url with latitude and longitude in browser, it returned  me the expected output that I should get from this JSON call. But not working in code.

Comment: In this code your function has no closing tag (I had to edit the question to correct the indentation, and now you can see it). Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I messed with this for a bit and the realized that sometimes it's the simplest solution... try requesting the secure (**https**) URL:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lon="+long+"&units=imperial&APPID=7a26948f2294e4d5754c951a6aaf7cf8", function(json) {  
    console.log("Successfully data recieved");
    var temp = Math.round(json.main.temp);
    console.log(temp);
    $("#weather").value(temp);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not properly closed, you missed ending `}` brace (I guess it is a typo). I've tried your code and it works for me like a charm. Also Be sure your `**jquery** library is included perfectly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
    <style>
        img {
            height: 100px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    (function() {
        getWeather(23.8008983,90.3541741);
    })();


    function getWeather(lat, long){
        var watherAPI = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lon="+long+"&units=imperial&APPID=7a26948f2294e4d5754c951a6aaf7cf8";
        $.getJSON( watherAPI, function (json) {
            console.log("Successfully data recieved");
            var temp = Math.round(json.main.temp);
            console.log(temp);
        })}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "https" gives me the solution by the way.

Comment: @Mohammad Nakib , But I get the data without https, just using http.